# C# how to split a string on the basis of <> character

Tags: c#, regex

I want to split my text by <> characters.

Example suppose I have a string

```
 string Name="this <link> is my <name>";
```

Now I want to split this so that I have a array of string like

```
ar[0]="this "
ar[1]="<link>"
ar[2]=" is my "
ar[3]="<name>"
```

I was trying with split function like

```
string[] ar=Name.Split('<');
```

I have also tried

```
 string[] nameArray = Regex.Split(name, "<[^<]+>");
```

But this is not giving me

```
 "<link>"
 and "<name>"
```

But it is not a good approach.
Can I use **regular expression** here.

Comment: See top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @RikHemsley: This question isn't related to any flavour of Xml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=.)(?=<)|(?<=>)(?=.)");
foreach (var s in r.Split("this_<link>_is_my_<name>"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

gives

```
this_
<link>
_is_my_
<name>
```

(underscores used for clarity)

The regex splits on a zero-width point (so it doesn't remove anything) which is either:

- preceeded by something and followed by `<`
- preceeded by `>` and followed by something

The "something" checks are necessary to avoid empty strings at the start or end if your string starts or ends with something in brackets.

Note something like `"<link<link>>"` will give you `{ "<link", "<link>", ">" }` so try to make your angle brackets balance.

If you *want* empty strings if the string starts with `<` or ends with `>` you can use `(?=<)|(?<=>)`. If you want empty strings *in the middle* when you encounter `><`, I *think* you need to first split on `(?=<)` and then split all the results on `(?<=>)` - I don't *think* you can do it in one go.

Comment: thanks for the solution but you have modified from "(?=<)|(?<=>)" to (?<=.)(?=<)|(?<=>)(?=.) why previous too was working?

Comment: @krshekhar That was to avoid empty strings at the start and end if your string starts or ends with angle-brackets. If you don't care about this - or want such strings - the first version should be fine. IF you want an empty string in between `><` I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: @downvoter Care to comment? As far as I can tell, this works. If there's a situation where it doesn't work, tell me.